# Unable to create Controller and model in php laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new at php laravel framework.

how model and controller are created through composer? phr write the commands to create model and controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use artisan not composer. To view all the commands you can run:

`php artisan list`

To make a controller and model you can run:

`php artisan make:model -c Awesome`

This will generate a `Controller` named `AwesomeController.php` file in your `Http\Controllers\` directory. It will also generate a `Model` named `Awesome.php` in the `App` directory by default.

Answer (score 2):

To create a model just run in console
`php artisan make:model <model name>` (e. g. `php artisan make:model Test)

To create a controller
`php artisan make:controller <controller name>` (e. g. `php artisan make:controller TestController`)
You can also change a path where to create a new class:
`php artisan make:controller NewFolder/Test`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php artisan make:model Test -mcr
```

This command will create Model User, migration User, Controller User with resources.